# JQuery Reference Error (Safari Specific)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, safari

My Code seems to work on `Chrome`/`IE`/`Firefox` but when it comes to `Safari` I get an error (See Below). I am using `Safari 8.0.8`.

I am trying to add up the values of the select options once selected and create a total. The total will change on change of course. I know it seems to be when creating a `global var` and then trying to access it with `safari` but I can't seem to get it to work.

The solution has to work on mobile also as it is being build for mobile but not working on iPhone either. I am using `JQuery` and `JQuery Mobile`.

Is there another way around this? Could I simplify the `JQuery` (there will be 30 selections to choose from, i'd need this `smaller` and more `efficient`)?

**Error**:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: previous
```

**Snippet**:

```js
$('#select-choice-timely').on('click', function () {
    previous = this.value;
}).change(function () {
    var a = $('#fr-total').html();
    var ab = parseInt(a, 10) - parseInt(previous, 10);
    var b = $(this).val();
    var c = parseInt(ab, 10) + parseInt(b, 10);
    $('#fr-total').html(c);
});
```

```html
<html class=""><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="robots" content="noindex"><link rel="canonical" href="http://codepen.io/JamieSterling/pen/QjyxGz">

<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<style class="cp-pen-styles"></style></head><body>
<div data-role="page" id="page-site-data">
  <div data-role="panel" data-display="push" id="mypanel" data-theme="b">
    <div class="user">
      <h3>Dave Smith</h3>
      <p><a href="/" class="">Logout</a></p>
    </div>
    <ul id="menu-panel" class="ui-listview ui-listview-b" data-role="listview">
      <li class=""><a href="/home.html" class="ui-link ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-home">Home</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#page-2" class="ui-link ui-btn">High performance finance</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#page-3" class="ui-link ui-btn">Peer review</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#page-4" class="ui-link ui-btn">Tools</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#page-5" class="ui-link ui-btn">Diary</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#page-6" class="ui-link ui-btn">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /panel -->
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Business Unit</h1>
    <a href="/site-1.html" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-hotback" data-role="none" data-icon="hotback" data-iconpos="left" role="button">Back</a>
  </div>
  <!-- /header -->
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <h2>Add Performance Data</h2>
    <form id="add-data-1">
      <fieldset data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" data-collapsed="false" id="fr">
        <legend>Financial Reporting</legend>
        <div class="ui-field-contain" id="timely-report">
          <label for="select-choice-timely" class="select">Timely Report</label>
          <select name="select-choice-timely" id="select-choice-timely" data-mini="true" data-inline="true">
          
            <option value="1">Basic</option>
          
            <option value="2">Developed</option>
          
            <option value="3">Advanced</option>
          
            <option value="4">High Performance</option>
          
            <option value="5">World Class</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-field-contain">
          <label for="select-choice-accurate" class="select">Accurate Reporting</label>
          <select name="select-choice-accurate" id="select-choice-accurate" data-mini="true" data-inline="true">
          
            <option value="1">Basic</option>
          
            <option value="2">Developed</option>
          
            <option value="3">Advanced</option>
          
            <option value="4">High Performance</option>
          
            <option value="5">World Class</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-field-contain">
          <label for="select-choice-efficient" class="select">Efficient Processes</label>
          <select name="select-choice-efficient" id="select-choice-efficient" data-mini="true" data-inline="true">
          
            <option value="1">Basic</option>
          
            <option value="2">Developed</option>
          
            <option value="3">Advanced</option>
          
            <option value="4">High Performance</option>
          
            <option value="5">World Class</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-field-contain">
          <label for="select-choice-harmonised" class="select">Harmonised &amp; Flexible</label>
          <select name="select-choice-harmonised" id="select-choice-harmonised" data-mini="true" data-inline="true">
          
            <option value="1">Basic</option>
          
            <option value="2">Developed</option>
          
            <option value="3">Advanced</option>
          
            <option value="4">High Performance</option>
          
            <option value="5">World Class</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-field-contain">
          <label for="select-choice-measured" class="select">Measured &amp; Monitored Performance</label>
          <select name="select-choice-measured" id="select-choice-measured" data-mini="true" data-inline="true">
          
            <option value="1">Basic</option>
          
            <option value="2">Developed</option>
          
            <option value="3">Advanced</option>
          
            <option value="4">High Performance</option>
          
            <option value="5">World Class</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
          <label for="select-choice-fr-total">Total</label>
          <div id="fr-total">5</div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>

      <button type="submit" id="submit-1" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all">Submit Data</button>

    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- /content -->
</div>
<!-- /page -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

**Link**:

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/JamieSterling/pen/QjyxGz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems in Safari the `change` fires before the `click`, therefore `previous` is undefined in the `change`-callback.

A different approach:

```
$("#select-choice-timely").change(function() {

  var a = $("#fr-total").html();
  var ab = parseInt(a, 10) - parseInt($(this).prop('previous'), 10);
  var b = $(this).val();
  var c = parseInt(ab, 10) + parseInt(b, 10);

  $("#fr-total").html(c);
  $(this).prop('previous',this.value)
}).prop('previous',function(){return this.value});
```

Comment: Thanks! It took me awhile to get my head around this problem.